# Jasypt Integration With Hibernate 4 and spring 3.1

Tags: spring, hibernate, jasypt

I am using **Spring 3.1** + **Hibernate 4.1** in my application. I want some fields(like password) to be stored in ***encrypted*** form using **Jasypt**. But in the integration i am facing exception below:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType.nullSafeSet(Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;Ljava/lang/Object;ILorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V
```

For integration of spring+hibernate with Jasypt, i followed following steps:

1. Added **jasypt-1.8.jar** in lib folder.
2. Added following in **dispatcher-servlet**(Config File)

   < bean id="hibernateStringEncryptor"
           class="org.jasypt.hibernate.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor"
           lazy-init="false">
           
               hibernateStringEncryptor
           
           
               jasypt
           
       < / bean>
3. Placed Following code on **Entity**:

   @TypeDef(
                   name="encryptedString",
                   typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class,
                   parameters= {
                           @Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName", value="hibernateStringEncryptor")
                           }
                   )

But it doesn't getting the expected result. Please help me to resolve this exception.

Regards,

Arun Kumar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the javadocs for [EncryptedStringType](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/hibernate/type/EncryptedStringType.html):

> A Hibernate 3 UserType implementation which allows transparent
> encryption of String values during persistence of entities.

And according to the [Hibernate 4 Migration Guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40):

> References to org.hibernate.usertype.UserType methods should be changed as indicated:
>
> nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner) should be changed to
> nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
> nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) should be changed to
> nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)

so jasypt 1.8 wouldn't be compatible with Hibernate 4.x.

You'll have to upgrade to jasypt 1.9, which according to [this](http://www.jasypt.org/whatsnew19.html#Hibernate_4_support) offers Hibernate 4 support.

EDIT:

The [Jasypt documentation](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html) provides a good overview.

This first sentence:

> Jasypt provides the jasypt-hibernate3 and jasypt-hibernate4 artifacts
> for Hibernate integration. Since jasypt 1.9.0, these artifacts must be
> added to your classpath separately.

So you will need to add jasypt-hibernate4.jar to your classpath to resolve the compile error.

Comment: I tried with  jasypt-1.9.jar too, but then it gives the Compile time error of the import `org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType`; Can you please help me for some integration tutorial of Jascypt with Hibernate 4 or some example if any?

Comment: Ohh..the mistake was that i used old import  `org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType` of hibernate 3 And when i replaced it with `org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType`, the problem gets solved. Its working now.